# Router.navigate в слушателе dom события

Tags: javascript, angular

Проект на Angular.

Задача состоит в том, что если у пользователя приложение открыто в двух вкладках и он выходит из системы в одной вкладке, то во второй вкладке url должен измениться на /login. Данные о пользователе хранятся в localStorage. Я подписываюсь на событие `storage` объекта `window`. Оно вызывается, если свойства в localStorage как-то изменяется.

```
private _redirectIfUserLoggedOut(): void {
  window.addEventListener('storage', this._onStorageListener);
}

private _onStorageListener = () => {
  const currentUser = localStorage.getItem('__session_token');

  if (!currentUser) {
    this._router.navigate(['/login']) // this call doesn't work
  }
}
```

Этот код находится в UserService, в который инджектится Router. Проблема в том, что `this._router.navigate не работает`. Просто ничего не происходит. Но если эту строку поменять на `window.location.href = '/login'`. То url менятся, но при этом происходит перезагрузка. При этом `this` и `this._router` **не равны undefined**

Comment: все логично вполне, попробуйте `window.addEventListener('storage', ()=>this._onStorageListener());`. А еще лучше использовать `@HostListener`, потому что от `window.addEventListener` надо отписаться еще.

Comment: а зачем fat arrow в еще одну fat arrow оборачивать?

Comment: А вы попробуйте и узнаете) Потому что ваше событие, повешенное через  window.addEventListener, работает вне скоупа ангулара.

Comment: не работаетn ;(

Comment: Очень интересно! Попробуйте тогда через `@HostListener`

Comment: @HostListener('window:storage') - вот так? этот код будет работать в сервисе?

Comment: Не уверен, что он будет работать в сервисе. Скорее всего не будет. Вам нужно использовать или в компоненте или посмотрите ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592972/is-it-possible-to-use-hostlistener-in-a-service-or-how-to-use-dom-events-in-an

Comment: Или, попробуйте использовать [ngZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)